# python dictionary value based on external class method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary with several key-value pairs.
What I want is that one value is set by a class method.

**Note: this is a sample class for the sake of the question, it has nothing to do with the actual scenario, just an example. PLEASE read this before answering or insulting me.**

```
class setPreposition:
    has_at = ['library', 'movies']
    has_on = ['table', 'train']

    def at_on_in(self, place):
        if (place in has_at):
            return 'at the' + place
        elif (place in has_on):
            return 'on the' + place
        return 'in the' + place
```

This is the dictionary:

```
SAMPLE_DICT = {
    'randomPlace': myClss.getPlace, #'movies' - random, comes from another method.
    'phrase': setPreposition.at_on_in(randomPlace),  # How to call the method here?
    'key2': 'something else'
}
```

***Again, this is a simple placeholder class and dictionary, I just want to know how can I call a method of a given class from within a dictionary (sending one or more parameters), that's it.***

Comment: The way you **always** call a method on an instance, you 1) need to have an instance, so `my_instance = setPreposition()`, then 2) you need to just call the method as you normally would: `{"phrase": my_instance._at_on_in("movies"), ...}"`. Note, you don't have a class method here, you have an instance method, which I am assuming is what you mean

Comment: You might also reconsider making a class, if you don't need instances to store anything. It would be totally fine to write `at_on_in` as a top-level function. If you're just grouping things together, consider using a module.

Comment: And people here LOVE minimal reproducible examples, so no need to worry about using apparently useless examples if they keep things minimal. Nobody is going to insult you, at any case, they may ask for more info.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly In an appropriate comment like yours, type `[mre]` for convenience. It gets you [mre].

Comment: I've seen things like "Why would you use a dict and class for such a st*pid task" or "why not just add the conditional in-line". I just wanted to be cautious... just in case. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to make `at_on_in()` a `static method`, so that you don't have to create an object of `setPreposition` class to call the method.

Furthermore, you cannot access another `key` within a `dict`, while creating the `dict`. So, one way to do it would be to store return value of `myClss.getPlace()` before creating a `dict` then using it.

```py
class setPreposition:
    has_at = ['library', 'movies']
    has_on = ['table', 'train']

    @staticmethod
    def at_on_in(place):
        if place in setPreposition.has_at:
            return 'at the ' + place
        elif place in setPreposition.has_on:
            return 'on the ' + place
        return 'in the ' + place

random_place = myClss.getPlace()
SAMPLE_DICT = {
    'phrase': setPreposition.at_on_in(random_place),
    'key2': 'something else'
}

>>> print(SAMPLE_DICT) # if random_place == 'movies'
>>> {'phrase': 'at the movies', 'key2': 'something else'}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! I updated the question though, kindly take a look. How could I send a value from the same dictionary as parameter? Let's say that other value is random and comes from another method, then I want to call the given method with that value as parameter.

Comment: As far as my knowledge, I don't think that's possible. So, one way would be to call ```myClss.getPlace``` before creating a ```dict``` and store it in a variable, then passing that variable to ```setPreposition.at_on_in``` while creating a ```dict```.

Comment: see the updated answer